# How to call OPL by doopl while defining the objective function in Python?

Tags: python, cplex, opl, doopl

Dears,

I have an optimization model that was built using OPL. The model works fine but I would like to use an objective function that is defined in Python. My question is can I use doopl to call the OPL model into python and use the objective function from Python (not from OPL).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that with docplex.

Let me use the [zoo example](https://medium.com/ibm-data-ai/optimization-simply-do-more-with-less-zoo-buses-and-kids-66940178db6)

In OPL you can write

```
int nbKids=300;
float costBus40=500;
float costBus30=400;
 
dvar int+ nbBus40;
dvar int+ nbBus30;
 

 
subject to
{
 40*nbBus40+nbBus30*30>=nbKids;
} 

main
{
  thisOplModel.generate();
  cplex.exportModel("zoo.lp");
}
```

that has no objective and will generate zoo.lp

```
Minimize
 obj1:
Subject To
 c1: 40 nbBus40 + 30 nbBus30 >= 300
Bounds
      nbBus40 >= 0
      nbBus30 >= 0
Generals
 nbBus40  nbBus30 
End
```

And then in python you can write

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model
from docplex.mp.model_reader import ModelReader


mdl = ModelReader.read_model('zoo.lp', model_name='zoo')

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v)

nbbus40 = mdl.find_matching_vars('nbBus40')[0]
nbbus30 = mdl.find_matching_vars('nbBus30')[0]

print(nbbus40)


mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)

mdl.solve(log_output=True,)

print("solution is empty : ",mdl.solution.is_empty())

print("obj : ",mdl.solution.get_objective_value())

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)
```

that will read the constraint and add a python objective

```
mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)
```

and give

```
obj :  3800.0
nbBus40  =  6.0
nbBus30  =  2.0
```

The call to the OPL model can be done from doopl , will generate zoo.lp that will be used by docplex

And the same works with CPOptimizer

```
using CP;

int nbKids=300;
float costBus40=500;
float costBus30=400;
 
dvar int+ nbBus40;
dvar int+ nbBus30;
 

 
subject to
{
 40*nbBus40+nbBus30*30>=nbKids;
} 

main
{
  thisOplModel.generate();
  cp.exportModel("zoo.cpo");
}
```

generates zoo.cpo

```
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
// IBM ILOG CP Optimizer model export file
// Effective workers: 12
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------

// ------ Integer variables: ------------------------------------------------

nbBus40 = intVar(0..intmax);
nbBus30 = intVar(0..intmax);

// ------ Constraints: ------------------------------------------------------

40*nbBus40 + 30*nbBus30 >= 300;
```

And

from docplex.cp.model import CpoModel

```
mdl = CpoModel(name='buses')

mdl.import_model("zoo.cpo")

vars=mdl.get_all_variables()

for i in vars:
    print(i.name)
    if (i.name=="nbBus40"):
        nbbus40=i
    if (i.name=="nbBus30"):
        nbbus30=i    

mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)

msol=mdl.solve()

print(msol[nbbus40]," buses 40 seats")
print(msol[nbbus30]," buses 30 seats")
```

gives

```
6  buses 40 seats
2  buses 30 seats
```

Comment: Hi Alex,
Thanks a million for your reply. Could you please clarify the following: 
1. Why the .*lp file was used. 
2. How to tackle this problem if CP solver is used.
3. What if I have all the constraints defined in the *.mod file and all the data are within the *.dat file, will be there a difference. 
Thanks in advance
Mohamed

Comment: 1. .lp is used to send the model from OPL to docplex. 2. same with cpoptimizer but you need to use .cpo file format 3.  Works fine with .dat files too

Comment: Thanks Alex. What if I would like to call a decision interval (dvar interval) instead of  (davr), how can this be done?

Comment: See https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zooimportoplmodelandaddpythonobjectivecposcheduling.py that is part of https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-optimization-simple-python-alex-fleischer/